# How to hookup BQ26231 Coulomb Counter

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, esp32

How would I hook up a battery Coulomb Counter ([link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq26231.pdf?ts=1658090275369&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ26231)) to report battery levels for a 3.7 V Li-ion cell to an ESP32 C3 microcontroller ([Link](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf)).

pinout for fuel gauge:
[image]

So right now the logic is to connect the positive terminal of the Li-ion cell to Vcc. But then I am confused what to do with SR1 (BAT-). Do I use plug it in parallel with VSS (Battery ground) or do I leave SR1 floating? What do HDQ, RBI, and SR2 do?

Comment: There are simpler gauges from TI that have I2C interface. HDQ is Apple's proprietary interface.

Answer (score 1):

That IC is a Coulomb Counter, not a Fuel Gauge. It leaves it up to you to implement the Fuel Gauge function. From the description: " It works with an intelligent host controller,... . By using the accumulated counts in the charge, discharge, and self-discharge registers, an intelligent host controller can determine battery state-of-charge information."

You need to connect the HDQ pin to the host computer. The spec sheet says "HDQ data input/output
This bidirectional input/output communicates the register information to the host system. HDQ is open drain and
requires a pullup/pulldown resistor in the battery pack to disable/enable sleep mode if the pack is removed from
the system."

You connect the SR1 and SR2 lines to the sense resistor, just as the schematic that you yourself posted shows.

Comment: Hey Davide, thank you for the clarification. I also want to ask what do the terminals on SR1 and SR2 represent? Specifically BAT- and PACK-.

Comment: I cannot explain it any better than the spec sheet,, which says: "SR1–SR2 current sense inputs
The bq26231 interprets charge and discharge activity by monitoring and integrating the voltage drop V (SR) across pins SR1 and SR2. The SR1 input connects to the sense resistor and the negative terminal of the battery.
The SR2 input connects to the sense resistor and the negative terminal of the pack. V (SR1) < V (SR2) indicates discharge, and V (SR1) > V (SR2) indicates charge. The effective voltage drop, V (SRO) , as seen by the bq26231, is V (SR) +V (OS) . Valid input range is ±200 mV.

Comment: Continued: "A 100 kΩ series resistor is recommended to protect these inputs
in case of a shorted battery.""

Answer (score 0):

Pack- is defined at the pack ground = system 0V point which also goes to Vss.

Bat- is for current sensing and is filtered going into SR2 and may be used elsewhere.